# Правильно ли добавляю ключ в словарь? Как вывести на печать ключи в строку?

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь:

```
directories = {
 '1': ['1000'],
 '2': ['145'],
 '3': [555],
 '4': []

}
```

Нужно дозаполнять словарь новыми ключами. Есть ключ уже есть в словаре, то выводить предупреждение. Если нет, то добавлять ключ в словарь и выводить в строку все ключи словаря.

Делаю так:

```
def ads_shelf(directories):
    input_number = input("Введите номер полки: ")
    if input_number not in directories:
        directories[input_number] = []
        print(f'Ключ успешно добавлен. Текущий перечень ключей:')
    else:
        print(f'Такой ключ существует. Текущий перечень ключей:')
```

Правильно ли делаю и как вывести ключи в строку принта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот смотрите, когда вы вот так проверяете, что ключа нет в словаре (и вы это делаете правильно), вам не надо никак специально указывать, что от словаря вы тут хотите именно список ключей, а не что-то другое, у `Python 3` такое поведение словарей прописано по умолчанию везде, где используется объект типа `dict`:

```
if input_number not in directories:
```

Поэтому для того, чтобы напечатать список ключей, достаточно взять объект `directories` как итератор и, например, проставить между его элементами запятые. Питон опять же сам догадается, что вы хотите именно ключи словаря, а не что-то другое:

```
print(f'Текущий перечень ключей: {",".join(directories)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if input_number not in directories:
    directories[input_number] = []
```

-- такие штуки обычно делаются через `collections.defaultdict(list)`. С defaultdict новые "полки" добавлять не нужно - они будут создаваться автоматически при записи.

Вывести все ключи просто

```
print(",".join(directories.keys()))
```